# Notification using Firebase and Android

Tags: java, android, firebase, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am trying to make an android application where I receive notification using firebase. I followed resources available over the internet.

All I want to do is send notification from firebase, the message that I receive I want to display it in TextView in main activity.

Currently I am testing in an emulator. There are few problems that I am not able to resolve.

I am able to send notification from firebase but:

1. When the application is running in foreground I don't receive a notification in the android notification panel and nothing happens in the main activity too. That is the text in TextView does not change.
2. When the application is running in background I do receive the notification in android notification panel with message sent from firebase, clicking the notification main activity opens but the text in TextView does not change.

Firebase Messaging Service

```
public class VAFirebaseMessagingService extends FirebaseMessagingService {

    private static final String TAG = "VAFirebaseMessagingS";

    public VAFirebaseMessagingService() {}

    @Override
    public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);

        Log.d(TAG, "From: " + remoteMessage.getFrom());
        if(remoteMessage.getData().size() > 0) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message data payload: " + remoteMessage.getData());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getData().get("text"));
        }

        if(remoteMessage.getNotification() != null) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Message Notification Body: " + remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
            sendNotification(remoteMessage.getNotification().getBody());
        }
    }

    private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageBody);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("PFIVA");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
}
```

Main Activity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private TextView userFeedbackQuery;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        userFeedbackQuery = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.pfiva_user_feedback_query);

        final Intent intent = getIntent();
        if(intent.hasExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT)) {
            String userFeedbackQueryText = intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT);
            userFeedbackQuery.setText(userFeedbackQueryText);
        }
    }
}
```

Android Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="de.pfiva.mobile.voiceassistant">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".activities.MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service android:name=".messaging.FirebaseInstanceService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.INSTANCE_ID_EVENT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

        <service
            android:name=".messaging.VAFirebaseMessagingService"
            android:enabled="true"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.google.firebase.MESSAGING_EVENT"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

Please can someone guide what is wrong here? How can i solve the above two problems.

Thanks

---

After suggestions i made the below changes in Messaging Service, basically added notification channel.

```
private void sendNotification(String messageBody) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class);
        intent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, messageBody);

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent
                .getActivity(this, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_ONE_SHOT);

        Uri defaultSoundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);

        NotificationCompat.Builder notificationBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this, CHANNEL_ID);
        notificationBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_stat_name);
        notificationBuilder.setContentTitle("PFIVA");
        notificationBuilder.setContentText(messageBody);
        notificationBuilder.setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH);
        notificationBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
        notificationBuilder.setSound(defaultSoundUri);
        notificationBuilder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

        NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        // Create the NotificationChannel, but only on API 26+ because
        // the NotificationChannel class is new and not in the support library
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
            int importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_DEFAULT;
            NotificationChannel channel = new NotificationChannel(CHANNEL_ID, CHANNEL_NAME, importance);
            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel);
        }

        notificationManager.notify(0, notificationBuilder.build());
    }
```

Problem i face now is that when the app is running in background, i do receive notification in notification panel and clicking on it open main activity but the text in TextView is not updated.

Comment: Please edit the question to describe exactly how you are sending the notification.

Answer (score 1):

Two ideas to solve your issue:

1. Have you register your `VAFirebaseMessagingService` in your AndroidManifest.xml:
2. Since Android 8, you must use an Notification Channel to send push notifications. [Android](https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/channels)

Comment: yes, i have also attached android manifest now. looking for changes with regards to notification channel

Comment: And now check your android version on your emulator ;) You can't receive notifiactions with your code above, when your device has version 8.0 or higher.

Comment: after adding the notification channel, things start to work but i have a problem when app runs in background. Now i receive notification both when app is running in foreground and background. When the app runs in foreground, the text in TextView is also updated. But when the app is running in background, after clicking on the notification in notification panel, the app comes to foreground but the text in TextView does not change. Please can you suggest. I have updated my chances above.

Comment: Problem is, that the background task can't send an intent to an not existing activity. So I think a good way is to save the text in SharedPreferences or SQLite Database and retrieve the text in the onCreate Method in your MainActivity.